# Rails loading my javascript only after a page reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this problem in Rails that when I enter the page, my javascript is not loaded. I have to reload the page after entering it and only then it loads.

This is how my javascript file looks like:

```
$(function() {
    initPage();
});
$(window).bind('page:change', function() {
    initPage();
});
function initPage() {
    window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById("buttons");
    var btn1 = document.createElement("button"); btn1.innerHTML = "Add one calculator"; btn1.id = "one";
    div.appendChild(btn1);
    btn1.onclick = function () {make_buttons ('calc');};
};

function make_buttons (id) {
    var div_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
    var input_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
    var operators = ["*","/","+","-","=","c","DEL"];
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
    var in_div = document.createElement("div"); in_div.id = div_id;
    parent.appendChild(in_div);
        var input = document.createElement("input"); input.type = 'text'; input.id = input_id; input.readOnly=true;
        in_div.appendChild(input);
        for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){  // make buttons with numbers
            var btn = document.createElement ("button");
            if (i === 0 || i === 6) {
                var br = document.createElement("br");
                in_div.appendChild(br);
            }
            btn.innerHTML = i;
            btn.id = i;
            in_div.appendChild(btn);
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {document.getElementById(input_id).value += index;};})(i);
        }
    for (var j = 0; j < operators.length; j++) {   // make buttons with operators
        var btn = document.createElement ("button");
        btn.innerHTML = operators[j];
        btn.id = operators[j];
        in_div.appendChild(btn);
        if (operators[j] === "=") {
            btn.onclick = function () {document.getElementById(input_id).value = eval(document.getElementById (input_id).value);};
        }
        else if (operators[j] === "c") {
            btn.onclick = function () {document.getElementById(input_id).value = '';};
        }
        else if (operators[j] === "DEL") {
            btn.onclick = function () {clearBox(div_id);};
        }
        else {
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {document.getElementById(input_id).value += index;};})(operators[j]);
        }   
    };
};

function clearBox(elementID) // delete the selected instance of calc
{
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML='';    
}  
}
```

Also I am using the turbolinks function in Rails.  What might be the problem here?

New code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {initPage();});
window.on('page:change', function(){initPage();});
/*
$(function() {
    initPage();
});
$(window).bind('page:change', function() {
    initPage();
});
*/
function initPage() {
        var div = document.getElementById("buttons");
        var btn1 = document.createElement("button"); btn1.innerHTML = "Add one calculator"; btn1.id = "one";
        div.appendChild(btn1);
        btn1.onclick = function () {make_buttons ('calc');};
}
function make_buttons (id) {
    var div_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
    var input_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
    var operators = ["*","/","+","-","=","c","DEL"];
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
    var in_div = document.createElement("div"); in_div.id = div_id;
    parent.appendChild(in_div);
        var input = document.createElement("input"); input.type = 'text'; input.id = input_id; input.readOnly=true;
        in_div.appendChild(input);
        for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){  // make buttons with numbers
            var btn = document.createElement ("button");
            if (i === 0 || i === 6) {
                var br = document.createElement("br");
                in_div.appendChild(br);
            }
            btn.innerHTML = i;
            btn.id = i;
            in_div.appendChild(btn);
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {document.getElementById(input_id).value += index;};})(i);
        }
    for (var j = 0; j < operators.length; j++) {   // make buttons with operators
        var btn = document.createElement ("button");
        btn.innerHTML = operators[j];
        btn.id = operators[j];
        in_div.appendChild(btn);
        if (operators[j] === "=") {
            btn.onclick = function () {document.getElementById(input_id).value = eval(document.getElementById (input_id).value);};
        }
        else if (operators[j] === "c") {
            btn.onclick = function () {document.getElementById(input_id).value = '';};
        }
        else if (operators[j] === "DEL") {
            btn.onclick = function () {clearBox(div_id);};
        }
        else {
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {document.getElementById(input_id).value += index;};})(operators[j]);
        }   
    };
};

function clearBox(elementID) // delete the selected instance of calc
{
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML='';    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `window.onload` inside the `initPage()` function.

`onload` event will be fired upload page loaded, but won't be fired again after `page:change` event. So the code inside `onload` block will never have chance to be executed after page changed.

To fix, remove `onload` logic from the function `initPage()`. Then, call `initPage()` on both `onload` and `page:change` event.

Comment: I think I still don't get it..  So I take out the whole onload block from initPage and leave that function empty. Then on the first line where it callc initPage(), I tell it to load but the page:change and onload?  But how do I tell it to do so?

Comment: I removed the window.onload alltogether and put what was inside of it into initPage. Now when loading the page for the first time, it loads my script but if I reload the page, it doubles the script. I suddenly have 2 buttons.

Comment: You just need to take out the block wrapper `window.onload = function () {});` and leave other code inside. Aslo I would prefer to use jQuery's document ready: `$(document).ready(function(){initPage()});` as well as `window.on('page:change', function(){initPage()});

Comment: I added new code to original post.  Bascily if I use the code in the comment tags, the script works on the first page load,  but it is always doubled(I see two objects of that script on the page). When I use the JQuery version,  I still need to reload the page to make the script visible.

Comment: Sorry, type too quick. It should be `$(window)` but not `window` which doesn't have jQuery method.

Comment: When going on the page via link,  it will load only one "Add one calculator" button. But when I refresh the page,  it makes two of them. What could cause that? That when I reload it it will use both the page ready and onload functions?

Comment: You made a button without logic to clean it. That may be the cause for such effect.

Comment: Well just weird, works outside of rails in a normal way.

Comment: Turbolinks generates its own methods. The event to listen for is `turbolinks:load`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks