# .js file only loads after refreshing the page in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I have the following JavaScript code on a rails project

```
// app/assets/javascript/simple_effects.js

$(function() {
  // Hide completed tasks when checkbox is clicked. projects/show
  $('#hide-completed').click(function() {
    $('.task-completed').toggle();
  });
  // Change label to checkbox that hides completed tasks. project/show
  $('#hide-completed').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? ' Show completed tasks' : ' Hide completed tasks';
    $('#checkbox-label').text(c);
  });

});
```

The code does not trigger when I enter the page but only after refreshing it. I am using turbolinks.

I am aware of this question:
[Rails loading my javascript only after a page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824522/rails-loading-my-javascript-only-after-a-page-reload)
But I don't really know if that solution can be used in my case as well.
Thank you!

Edit:
This is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: can you post your `application.js` file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a lot of existing JavaScript that binds elements on jQuery.ready(), you can pull the [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) library into your project that will trigger ready() when Turbolinks triggers the the page:load event. It may restore functionality of some libraries.

Add the gem to your project,

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

then add the following line to your JavaScript manifest file, after jquery.js but before turbolinks.js:

```
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: The application throws an error: couldn't find file 'jquery.turbolinks'

Comment: You must restart your rails server after adding this gem. Otherwise you get the error La Murga got.

Comment: Note that this does **not** work with turbolinks 5+, as noted on their github page: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using turbolinks 5+, `jquery-turbolinks` doesn't work anymore (see https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

Instead you can wrap your code into the function `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->`.

E.g.

```
$ ->
  $("#add-artwork-btn").on 'click', ->
    div = $("#add-artwork-div")
    div.toggle(200)
```

becomes to

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $ ->
    $("#add-artwork-btn").on 'click', ->
      div = $("#add-artwork-div")
      div.toggle(200)
```